# Cut locus on a hypercube

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Inspired by the question, "[Shortest path connecting two opposite points on a cube](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264805/6094)":

> ***Q***. What does the [cut locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) with respect to one corner of a hypercube
>   in $\mathbb{R}^d$ look like?

"The cut locus from a point $p$ on a surface is the closure
of the set of all points that have at least two shortest
paths connecting them to $p$."<sup>1</sup>

Here it is for $d=3$:

---

[image: CubeCutLocus]

          

<sup>Cut locus with respect to vertex $0$ is a star-tree rooted at vertex $6$.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Itoh, Jin-ichi, and Robert Sinclair. "Thaw: A tool for approximating cut loci on a triangulation of a surface." *Experimental Mathematics* 13.3 (2004): 309-325.